# Evaluating integral using Cauchy Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I wish to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{\log(z)}{z^n}$$
with $\gamma(t) = 1+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}, 0\le t \le 2\pi, n\ge 0.$

Now I tried to use the following Cauchy formula: 
$$ f^n(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}z. $$ 
where $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on $B(a;r) \subset G, \gamma(t) = a+re^{it}, 0\le t \le 2\pi.$

Since I need a $(z-1)^{n+1}$ in the denominator to use the above formula, I took $f(z) = \log(z)\frac{(z-1)^{n}}{z^n} = \log(z)\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^n $ and then tried to apply the formula, but then I can't see a simple way to find the derivative. I need to use multiple times the product rule which becomes cumbersome. Is there some elegant way to do this calculation or I am totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that, in this context, $\log$ is the main logarithm, then that integral is $0$, since $\frac{\log z}{z^n}$ has no singularities in the region bounded by $\gamma\bigl([0,2\pi]\bigr)$.

Comment: But I need $(z-1)^n$ in the integral formula right?? So how do I get it in the form as you have shown?

Comment: My previous answer was wrong. What do you think now?

Comment: I think this is correct, taking the branch of the logarithm to be the principal branch. I was naive enough to not see that the function $\log(z)/z^n$ is analytic in the region. My bad.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I was more focused on using the formula.